# Qt QCompleter does not pop out

Tags: qt, cjk, qmap, qcompleter

## Problem description

I want to be able to recognize the corresponding Chinese person name and complete the prompt by entering a short Chinese phonetic alphabet.

For example, I have a map (("lvbu", "吕布"), ("lvbuwei", "吕不韦")) , then enter "lv" or "bu". The completer should pop up "吕布" and "吕不韦", but it seems that the `stringlist` must contain the content currently being entered to complete the prompt. The completer cannot recognize the mapping relationship.

How can I solve this? I can hardly find a solution on the Internet because it involves Chinese.

## My code

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "Pinyin2Hanzi/myPinyin.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QString N = "吕布 吕不韦 南宫问天";
    QStringList Names = N.split(" ");
    // qDebug() << Names;

    ui->comboBox->addItem("");
    ui->comboBox->addItems(Names);
    ui->comboBox->lineEdit()->setClearButtonEnabled(true);
    CreateCompleter(Names, ui->comboBox->lineEdit());

    ui->comboBox->setMaxCount(ui->comboBox->count()); //这行代码可以防止按回车键自动往combobox里addItem

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

std::map<std::string, std::vector<QString>> pinyin2NameMap; // This is a private variable

// 把所有人名按照拼音分类并存入map中
void MainWindow::PreparePinyinData(const QStringList &names)
{
    for (auto & name : names)
    {
        QString outFristPy,outFullPy;
        getComPingyinForStr(name, outFristPy, outFullPy);
        //        QString pinyin = GetPinyin(name);
        QString pinyin = outFullPy;
        // qDebug() <<"FristPy:" << outFristPy << "FullPy:" << outFullPy;
        // qDebug() <<"pinyin:" << pinyin;

        // QString fist, last;
        // myNameSplit(name, last, fist); // 自动切分 [姓、名]
        // last = getNamePingyin(last, true); // 获取 [姓] 的拼音
        // fist = getNamePingyin(fist, false);// 获取 [名] 的拼音
        // qDebug() << name + " : " + last + " " + fist << endl;
        pinyin2NameMap[pinyin.toStdString()].push_back(name);
    }
}

// 根据输入的拼音进行匹配并获取提示列表
QStringList MainWindow::GetMatchByPinyin(const QString &pinyin)
{
    QStringList result;
    if("" == pinyin.trimmed()){
        return QStringList();
    }
    for (const auto & iter : pinyin2NameMap){
        if (iter.first.find(pinyin.toStdString()) != std::string::npos){
            auto vec = iter.second;
            for(const auto & name : vec){
                result.append(name);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// 创建QCompleter并设置自动补全模型
void MainWindow::CreateCompleter(const QStringList &names, QLineEdit *lineEdit)
{
    PreparePinyinData(names);
    QStringListModel *model = new QStringListModel(names);
    QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(model, lineEdit);
    completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    completer->setFilterMode(Qt::MatchContains);
    completer->setCompletionMode(QCompleter::PopupCompletion);
    lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
    connect(lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textEdited, [this,completer,lineEdit, model](const QString &text)
    {
        QStringList matchList = GetMatchByPinyin(text);
        qDebug() << "listmodel:" << matchList;
        // QString N = "lv不bu 可lvbuwei nan够gongwentian";
        // QStringList matchList = N.split(" ");
        model->setStringList(matchList);
        completer->setModel(model);
        completer->complete();
    });
}
```

Comment: *"How can I solve it? I can hardly find a solution on the Internet because it involves Chinese."*, do you mean it works for US ASCII strings, and breaks only if there is chinese Unicode?

Comment: @hyde Perhaps in fact, the problem lies in the joint use of qcompleter and qmap rather than character coding

Comment: @hyde In the exe, if i set the stringlistmodel just as ("lvbu","lvbuwei"), the completer would pop out when i enter "lv" or "bu", because the Enters is contained in the completer stringlist. But when I further use qmap keys(such as "lvbu" or "lvbuwei") to retrieve Chinese words(such as "吕布" or "吕不韦") to append in the completer stringlist, the completer isn't pop out when i enter "lv" or "bu".